# How to make repetitive xml nodes and save different values in them without overwriting

Tags: php, xml

I have created an form and i am uploading images though that form, and i created a node in XML file, and i want to save the name of image in that file, all things are working but whenever i upload new pic it just replace the older file name, all i want to do that if i upload one more pic then it should create one more node automatically and then add the image name there dynamically without replacing the older one.

Form i used :

```
<div id="popup_box_slider_image" class="Add-Social-Media">
<!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->
<a id="popupBoxClosesliderImage"  class="ClosePopup"></a>
<form id="addEditFormSelectTemplate" action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p>Please upload a image to add to slider.</p>
<br />
<div style="width:100%; float:left;">
<br/>
```

Upload Image:

```
<input type="file" name="sliderImage" id="slider" value="" style="width:180px;" class="field-box"  />
<br />
<span id="sliderImageErr">&nbsp;</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div align="left">
<input type="submit" name="SelectsliderImage" onClick="return validatesliderImage();"  value="Update" style="background-color:#2D69A9 ; color:#FFFFFF ; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; border:none ; cursor:pointer ; border-radius:5px; " />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP code i used:

```
$sliderimagename=$_FILES['sliderImage']['name'];
$xmlpath=SITE_URL."xml/".$_SESSION['username']."/test.xml";
$document=simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);
$document->body->sliderimage = $sliderimagename;
$document->asXML($xmlpath);
$path=SITE_URL."/slider_images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sliderImage']['tmp_name'],$path.$sliderimagename);
```

XML node structure :

```
<body>
    <title>changeBg</title>
    <imagename>B4.jpg</imagename>
    <sliderimage></sliderimage>
</body>
```

Comment: How about [`adding a child`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to the document after you've loaded it?

Comment: will you please illustrate a bit, actually i am very new to it. i hope you will not mind it.

Answer (score 2):

By using the [`addChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) method of the SimpleXMLElement you want to add new children to.
Using the your current xml structure, it would look something like this:

```
//...
$document=simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);
$new_image = $document->body->addChild('sliderimage', $_FILES['sliderImage']['name']);
```

This would result in an xml output like this:

```
<body>
    <title>changeBg</title>
    <imagename>B4.jpg</imagename>
    <sliderimage></sliderimage>
    <sliderimage></sliderimage> <!-- this is the newly created node -->
</body>
```

But you would probably want to restructure your xml file to so you can have one more level of nesting, for example like this:

```
<body>
    <file> <!--- new top level tag to group the individual images -->
        <title>changeBg</title>
        <imagename>B4.jpg</imagename>
        <sliderimage>old image</sliderimage>
    </file>
    <file>
        <!--- ... -->
        <sliderimage>new image</sliderimage>
    </file>
</body>
```

In this case you just have to call the `addChild` multiple times on the returned node like this:

```
$new_file = $document->body->addChild('file'); // adding a new <file> node
$new_file->addChild('title', 'some title'); // adding more nodes inside the new <file> node
$new_file->addChild('imagename', '...');
// ...
```

Comment: yours is a bit more fleshed out, should have submited quicker mine - upvote

Comment: @complex857 Thanks a lot mate, its working exactly the way i want.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Add a new child element:
$document->body->addChild('sliderimage', $sliderimagename);

```
<body>
<title>changeBg</title>
<imagename>B4.jpg</imagename>
<sliderimage>First</sliderimage>
<sliderimage>Second</sliderimage>
</body>
```

you however should probably change xml to indicate that there is a set of items available

```
<body>
<title>changeBg</title>
<imagename>B4.jpg</imagename>
<sliderimages>
    <image>First</image>
    <image>Second</image>
</sliderimages>
</body>
```